# How enable PUT method in apache php 5.0

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, put

I have a content in htaccess

```
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule .* index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

How do I add to enable PUT method?
Thanks

Comment: Besides simplification, is there any benefit in using PUT over POST in your context?

Comment: Enable PUT to do what? There's nothing to do to enable PUT requests to work with PHP, unless your base config blocks it. I'm not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: The `RewriteRule` directives in the `.htaccess` look like that they are in conflict with each other.

Comment: @PHPConnect - because maybe he's creating a RESTful  web service. So if he's creating a resource he'll use POST and if he's updating a resource he'll use PUT. Like you should with RESTful web services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution which may work for you

1. First, a utility file to support HTTP digest authentication, which
   can be located in the target directory (or a common PHP include
   directory if you can set one up): [dowload and rename dauth.php](http://www.w3.org/Amaya/User/dauth_php.example)
2. Second, in the directory concerned, place the following PHP script:
   [download and rename put.php](http://www.w3.org/Amaya/User/put_php.example)
3. Third, store the following .htaccess file in the target directory,
   replacing '/path-to-target-directory' with the domain-relative path
   (e.g. if a target file can be read at http://mydomain/x/y/z.html,
   then the /path-to-target-directory would be '/x/y'): [download and rename .htaccess](http://www.w3.org/Amaya/User/htaccess.example)

`.htaccess` example:

```
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /path-to-target-directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !PUT
RewriteRule ^/put\.php$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} PUT
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/put\.php$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} PUT
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ put.php?url=$1 [L]
```

For more info refer: [Here](http://www.w3.org/Amaya/User/Put.html)

Answer (score 0):

Conventions talk about the `X-HTTP-METHOD-OVERRIDE` header that transports the underlying method to be used (in a POST request).

You can get this request header in your php application to define whether or not you handle a PUT request.

Answer (score 0):

No action is required to "enable" PUT requests with apache.

if you mean that you don't receive the data sent with a PUT request - you need some php code like this in your code:

```
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'PUT') {
     $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
 }
```

since a PUT request will not populate `$_POST` (obviously, since it's not a POST request).